# Component is not injecting in index.html file using grunt-wiredep

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bower, grunt-wiredep

Here is my code which finds components and injects them directly into the INDEX.HTML file.

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-wiredep');
wiredep: {
  target: {
    src: 'index.html' // point to your HTML file.
  }
}
```

and in index.html

```
< !-- bower:js -->
< !-- endbower -->
```

after that i install any library via bower like.

```
bower install jquery --save
```

and then

```
grunt wiredep
```

after that i got

> ➜ dc-customer-portal-spa git:(master) ✗ grunt wiredep --debug
>
> Running "wiredep:target" (wiredep) task [D] Task source:
>   /var/www/dc-customer-portal-spa/node_modules/grunt-wiredep/tasks/wiredep.js
>
> Done, without errors.

But not included in html file, Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

If the grunt code posted is the actual content of your gruntfile, you're missing the grunt.initConfig() call.

This should work better :

```
module.exports = function( grunt ){

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-wiredep');

    grunt.initConfig({
        wiredep: {
            target: {
                src: 'index.html' // point to your HTML file.
            }
        }
    });

};
```